# How to implement Search members functionality (Similar to Praise App) in Adaptive Card invoked via MS Team's Message Extension feature

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am working on MS-Team App which has features similar to Praise(Default app). This app will have "Message Extension" capability which will enable user to invoke it from bar/compose section and will show a wizard. The wizard is implemented through task/fetch-continue-submit workflow.

My question is that in Praise app, I can see a functionality of searching users and then adding it to a list(See attached image). I think that is built inside Adaptive Card but I don't see any such control/event in adaptive card to implement same thing. So how they have implemented it or there is something I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Is Amy T's answer acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with adaptive cards and will need to make your own custom UI to display via a task module response.

Over at the [adaptive cards feature portal](https://portal.productboard.com/adaptivecards/), you can vote for this as a feature to add: [Dynamic searchable select menu (like select2)](https://portal.productboard.com/adaptivecards/1-adaptive-cards-features/c/15-dynamic-searchable-select-menu-like-select2)

(I also would very much like to do this in an adaptive card from a messaging extension, so I'll be interested to hear if anyone else thinks there's a way to do it.)

Comment: So how is it done in Praise App? Are they also using Custom UI instead of using Adaptive Cards?

Comment: I'm not super-familiar with the app, but if I use it with Teams in a browser, so I can use F12 dev tools to watch the requests and responses that happen when using it, yes, it looks to me like it uses a custom UI developed with Fabric (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/).